# Как вывести в bbpress количество сообщений под аватаром?

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

Как вывести в bbpress количество сообщений под аватаром? Есть ли для этого специальный хук? Или нужно только править шаблон?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Adds Total messages + Reply link
add_action( 'bbp_theme_after_reply_author_details', 'apeo_messages_total' );
add_action( 'bbp_theme_after_topic_author_details', 'apeo_messages_total' );
function apeo_messages_total(){
    $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
    $topics = bbp_get_user_topic_count_raw($user_id);
    $replies = bbp_get_user_reply_count_raw($user_id);
    $messages = $topics + $replies;
    echo "<small>Сообщений: $messages</small><br>";
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo "<small>".bbp_get_reply_to_link()."</small>";
    }
}
```